# Sum of all pair shortest distance in DAG

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given a DAG with $n$ nodes and $n−1$ edges. The edges in DAG (fixed) is defined as follows: For every node $i, 1≤i≤n−1$ is connected to node $i+1$. The weight of $n−1$ edges are given. For every pair $u,v (u<v)$ I need to find the shortest distance (which in fact is the direct distance between them as there are no multiple edges).

Assuming the weight between node$i,i+1=a_i$.

Then for $n=2$ nodes ,dist=$ a_1$.

for $n=3$ nodes dist= $a_1+(a_1+a_2)+a_2$.

for $n=4$ nodes dist =  $a_1+(a_1+a_2)+(a_1+a_2+a_3)+(a_2)+(a_2+a_3)+a_3$.

I thought the pattern would $(n-1)*$sum of all $a_i$ so that answer becomes 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} [i*(n-1)*a_i]
\end{equation}
but it's not correct.

What would be the correct pattern ?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71433/755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean by a pattern is a summation formula then this is the one :

$$ \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum \limits_{j=i}^{n} (n-j+1) a_j$$

For an explanation start with node $1$ and go to $2$ you passed over one edge with length $a_1$, now from node $1$ to node $3$ you passed over two edges with lengths $a_1,a_2$ and so on.

so you will pass over the first edge $n$ times and the second edge $n-1$ times and so on, now you've got this summation $\sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} (n-j+1)a_j$ but now you will do the same thing but starting from node $2$ after that you will do the same thing starting from node $3$ and so on till $n-1$ which will give the complete summation formula stated above.

hope it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

- Take an arbitrary edge $(i,i+1)$ and observe that if a path uses this edge, then that path had to start at $j \leq i$.
- Similarly, it had to end after $k \geq i+1$.
- Now, separately for each edge, count the number of paths that use it.
- Calculate the total summing the above times the edges' weights.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$